# ubuntu10.04 can't mount USB Automatically,and can't access LAN via smb

Tags: automount

my ubuntu10.04 can't mount USB Automatically,I have to mount manually,and can't access LAN via smb command,I have tested is OK via ping

Answer (score 0):

Mountusb

```
Sudo apt-get install mountusb
```

Comment: hi,'mountusb' should be 'usbmount',I tried,but the usb0(FAT Partition) is can't write,other problem?